# How to Create a Directory in Internal Storage without using the Environment Class?

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

The Environment Class Method "new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ABC/");" works fine in lower Android Versions but it does not create any folder in My Emulator(Pixel 3, Android 10) and in Redmi Note 8 Pro(Android 9). After Googling, it turns out that the above method is deprecated. Is there any other methods to create Folders in the SD Card(External Storage)?

Comment: As getExternalStorageDirectory() has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card you better rephrase your question as now it does not make sense.